# Personally defining FALSE and TRUE a bad idea? Why?

Tags: c++, boolean

I've heard mentioned several times that defining these macros yourself is a bad idea, but I've not understood why.  Apparently 'false' and 'true' are part of C++ standard and 'FALSE' and 'TRUE' are not part of the standard.

However, 'FALSE' AND 'TRUE' are defined as macros in windows.h, and I've grown accustomed to it, and actually prefer them because they remind me that a boolean, after stripping it of any abstraction, is simply evaluated as an integer at the bit level.  Anyway, it's personal preference, but I was wondering would it really be a bad idea if I wanted to define my own macros in my program?  Any cogent reasons why it shouldn't be done?

One answer I've seen on Stack Overflow is that the person has seen disgruntled employees going through the code and inserting things such as:

```
#define FALSE 1
```

But apart from anything extremely remote and silly, is there any good reason not to?

Edit: Thanks for answers.  The reasons given here that I understand and agree with are: 
(from Ulrich Eckhardt)

- There are existing constants/keywords true and false that everyone knows.
- It conflicts with the macros in the win32 API, so your code would become nonportable to that platform.
- int const FALSE = 1; would achieve the same effect without the macro side effects.

(from Paul Evans)

- "you certainly don't want them to be 0 and 1, this will mess up things like calling functions overloaded with both bool and int."
- "Because macros are best avoided if possible. The preprocessor simply text-replaces all macro before the compiler even has a look-see. So you lose them as a source of information in say, debugging, etc."
- Define them as constant expressions and avoid macros

Thank you.

Comment: Would that look like `#define FALSE false` or `#define FALSE 0`. The later is a semantic change, the former will probably only confuse other people trying to work with you.

Comment: I'm saying if I kept it as the standard, where boolean false is 0, and true is 1, I thought that was pretty standard.  In fact as far as I know the lowercase 'true' and 'false' are equivalent to 1 and 0, that's what it fills the byte as (I think).  I also heard people saying "don't trust them because you never know what they'll be in the future", but 1 and 0 as true and false aren't going to change, are they?

Comment: What are the pros and cons you see?

Comment: Why stop there I say? Why not `FOR`, `WHILE`, `SWITCH`, `CASE`, `CLASS`, `STRUCT`, `RETURN` etc... etc...?

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt Technically the difference is so meaningless I shouldn't have asked the question.  The reason I was compelled to is that people on Stack Overflow commonly warn against it, and yet I can't see why, seeing as though you're only doing what's been done in the windows header in your own header, and maintaining a well known standard that 0 is false and non zero is true.  But yeah, the only difference is on my compiler one turns purple and the other turns lowercase dark blue.  I may as well make statements such as "isTurnedOn = 1" instead, it doesn't make a difference much to me.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice The types are different. That is not a meaningless difference. `foo(true)` and `foo(TRUE)` could have different overload resolution. I would say that is not a good thing.

Comment: Adding to @juanchopanza's comment, there are existing overloads that differ. `operator<<` for streams writes `true` and `false` or `1` and `0` depending on the `boolalpha` format flag if called with a `bool`.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice, to me (and probably others), `isTurnedOn = 1` is actively confusing because it assigns a number to something who's name suggests it can only be true or false. BTW: The existence of `BOOL` in the win32 API predates the first C++ standard. Also, it predates the C99 standard which introduced a boolean type in C.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, I shouldn't have said meaningless, I just mean whether it's formatted in uppercase or lowercase or what colour isn't so much important to me.  Yeah, I understand your example with the overloaded function. Hmm, guess I'd better stick to 'true' and 'false'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because macros are best avoided if possible.  The preprocessor simply text-replaces all macro before the compiler even has a look-see.  So you lose them as a source of information in say, debugging, *etc*.  Also you certainly don't want them to be `0` and `1`, this will mess up thing like calling functions overloaded with both `bool` and `int`.  If you really *must* have these capitalized names why not simple define them as constant expressions, something like:

```
constexpr bool TRUE{true};
constexpr bool FALSE{false};
```

Answer (score 5):

Bunch of reasons:

- `FALSE` requires one more keypress to type than `false`.
- Macros are evil.
- `int const FALSE = 1;` would achieve the same effect without the macro side effects.
- It would still look like a macro though.
- There are existing constants/keywords `true` and `false` that everyone knows.
- If you and only you are the only person ever working on that codebase, only then it becomes sufficiently clear.
- It conflicts with the macros in the win32 API, so your code would become nonportable to that platform.
- A `bool` is not an `int`.

Comment: This answer I would have accepted over the other one but the only good points in my opinion are points 3, 5 and 7.  And I never said a bool was an int as a datatype, only that a bool is evaluated like an integer in the sense that 0 is false and non-zero is true, and this low level understanding helps me personally.   Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other, very good answers in response to:

> I'm saying if I kept it as the standard, where boolean `false` is 0, and `true` is 1, I thought that was pretty standard. In fact as far as I know the lowercase 'true' and 'false' are equivalent to 1 and 0, that's what it fills the byte as (I think)

**No**. This is a *terrible* mistake. Whatever a boolean will at last be represented by the CPU (that *might* be 0 and 1) there's just the fact that **a boolean is *not* an integer**.

Pitfalls occur especially with respect to templates (`operator<<`) and overload resolution.

For the first, consider a class such as `std::vector` which implements [different behavior for boolean types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). In the case of `std::vector`, you probably only miss an optimization, but it could be far worse than that (as the behavior could be completely different).

For the second, consider this:

```
void frob(char c, size_t repeats) {
  cout << "frob(char, size_t)" << endl;
}
void frob(char c, bool flag, size_t optional = 42) {
  cout << "frob(char, bool, size_t)" << endl;
}

#define TRUE 1

int main() {
  frob('a', true);
  // frob('a', TRUE); // COMPILATION ERROR
  return 0;
}
```

This example might be very artificial, and in this case it's not even that  bad, because there's a compiler error that shows exactly what's wrong, but that might not apply to all real world cases.

Comment: Sorry, I understood when you assign 'true' or 'false' to a bool variable, it fills it with either a 1 integer or a 0 integer.  And that's why you can do things like 

bool isTurnedOn = false;
if (isTurnedOn == 0) {do something};

the == 0, or 1, being an int type.  

I'm aware a bool isn't an int as a datatype, like you've shown, the compiler won't let you send a bool value, or "bool literal" as I've heard it called, to a function that takes a size_t, even though size_t is just a typedef for one of the primitive data types, my understanding is that's for type safety.